# ExecAndWait - Extending ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security, interceptor, interceptorstack

Has any of you succeeded to extend the `ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor` and make your webapp use it ?
I followed [this example](https://svn.atlassian.com/svn/public/atlassian/vendor/webwork-2.2.x/trunk/docs/wikidocs/HibernateAndSpringEnabledExecuteAndWaitInterceptor.html), but my interceptor is never accessed. Do these classes need to be named in a specific way?

I believe I need to extend it because when I try to run `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` in my action, the authentication is null. My idea was to run this in the `beforeInvocation()` method.

Any ideas?

Thank you all!

**UPDATE** : Roman C.'s comment made it work! I added my interceptor to the `<interceptors>` area. This is the working struts.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="test" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/test">

        <interceptors>

            <interceptor name="myExecAndWaitInterceptor" class="xx.xxx.xxxx.action.FailureAvailabilityRateExecuteAndWaitInterceptor">
                <param name="delay">1000</param>
                <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
            </interceptor>

            <interceptor-stack name="newStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
                <interceptor-ref name="myExecAndWaitInterceptor"/>
            </interceptor-stack>

        </interceptors>


        <action name="failureAvailabilityRate" class="xx.xxx.xxxx.action.FailureAvailabilityRateAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="newStack"/>
            <result name="wait">/jsp/test/wait.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/jsp/test/failureAvailabilityRate.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/jsp/test/failureAvailabilityRate.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Show you `struts.xml` file.

Comment: You should define your custom interceptor under the `interceptors` tag.

Comment: There's another useful example - http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-execandwait-interceptor-example/